# ansible playbook that calls sub-playbooks

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to make several playbook calls in Ansible, but I can't seem to make it work with either import_playbook, include_task, or include (I believe include is deprecated).

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

I have a Python file that prompts the user to choose between two YAML files and then call scenario1.yml, which redirects to either local_deployement.yml or aws_deployement.yml based on the user's choice.

Here's the scenario1.yml content:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "Deployment in local mode"
      include_task: local_deployement.yml
      when: mode == "local"
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "Deployment in non-local mode"
      import_playbook: aws_deployement.yml
      when: mode == "nonlocal"
```

Next, local_deployement.yml is responsible for calling every local Ansible script:

```
# local_deployement.yml

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "Inclusion of tasks for local mode deployment"
      include_tasks: local_bdd_server.yml
      when: mode == "local"
    - include_tasks: local_ftp_server.yml
      when: mode == "local"
```

Finally, an example of local_bdd_server.yml would be as follows:`

```
# local_bdd_server.yml

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  tasks:
    - name: Install Docker and Docker-compose
      become: yes
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      with_items:
        - apt-transport-https
        - ca-certificates
        - curl
        - lsb-release
        - gnupg2
        - python3-pip
```

Unfortunately, it's getting stuck during the playbook call due to the parameters, but I don't understand why.

I am searching for the difference between include_task and import_tasks. I believe that include_task should be used for a list of tasks, so perhaps that's the issue because my database deployment is not a list of tasks but rather a regular playbook. However, I'm not sure how I should modify this.

Individually, everything seems to work fine. It's only when everything is combined that it stops working.

So if you any idea that's will really help thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have multiple design issues. It's better to solve them before you proceed further (and the first one is in fact a blocker):

1. `import_playbook` does not work as a task and it's [specifically mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html#examples)
2. > I have a Python file that prompts the user to choose between two YAML files and then call scenario1.yml, which redirects to either local_deployement.yml or aws_deployement.yml based on the user's choice.

   This is unnecessary. Just create an inventory and use the built-in [`--limit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html) CLI parameter:

   ```yaml
   # inventory
   ---
   all:
     hosts:
       aws:
         ansible_host: 'your_aws_api_url_goes_here'
   ```

   ```yaml
   # deployment.yaml
   ---
   - name: Deploy something
     hosts: all
     connection: local
     tasks:
       - name: Use AWS modules with ansible_host
         # ...
   ```

   This way, the playbook will run against your AWS environment by default. If someone wants to run the same locally, all they need to do is run this playbook with `--limit localhost` parameter.
3. `apt` module will work much faster if you pass the list of packages directly to `name` instead of calling it in a loop, which is also [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#id11):

   ```yaml
   # local_bdd_server.yml
   - hosts: localhost
     vars:
       ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
     tasks:
       - name: Install Docker and Docker-compose
         become: yes
         apt:
           update_cache: yes
           name:
             - apt-transport-https
             - ca-certificates
             - curl
             - lsb-release
             - gnupg2
             - python3-pip
           state: present
   ```